# Find surface area of cylinder $y^2 + z^2 = 1$ between two planes: $x + y - 2 = 0$ and $x-z+4 = 0$.

Tags: calculus

Find surface area of a cylinder $y^2 + z^2 = 1$ between two planes: $x + y - 2 = 0$,  $x-z+4 = 0$.

This was my approach:

I drew the picture and projected the figure onto $xOy$ plane, and after that I found partial detivatives $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} $ and $ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ where $z = + \sqrt{1-y^2}$. I choose the positive sqare root because of the symmetry, and that's why I will multiply following integral by $2$.

Eventually, my integral looks like this:

$P(S) = 2\begin{gather*}
    \iint_D \sqrt{1+ \frac{y^2}{1-y^2} + 0^2}\,dx\,dy = 
 2\iint_D \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\,dx\,dy = 
... = 9\pi
\end{gather*}
$ .

$D$ is $\{ -4 \leq x \leq 1 \land -1\leq y \leq 1  \} \cup \{ 1 \leq x \leq 3 \land  -1 \leq y \leq 2-x \}$

I wonder if this is correct and if anyone could tell me if I am wrong on this, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving this problem is easier if you parameterize this surface. Consider $$\vec{r}(u,v)=\big<u,\cos(v),\sin(v)\big>$$ for $\sin(v)-4 \leq u \leq -\cos(v)+2$ and $0\leq v \leq 2\pi$. The surface area in your question equals $$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{\sin(v)-4}^{-\cos(v)+2}||\vec{r}_u \times \vec{r}_v||dudv=12\pi$$

**Remark**: If you wanted to solve it your way, you wouldn't be able exploit the symmetry of the cylinder $y^2+z^2=1$ by the way it intersects the plane $x-z+4=0$. Calculating the surface area with $\int \int _{D}\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}dA$ gives $$\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-4-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{-y+2}\frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}+\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-4+\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{-y+2}\frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=12\pi$$

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to integrate the surface in cylindrical coordinates, with $z=r\cos \theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$,  $x=x$ and around the circle of radius $1$

$$A=\int_0^{2\pi} (x_2-x_1)\cdot 1\cdot d\theta
= \int_0^{2\pi} (2-\sin\theta -(\cos\theta -4))d\theta=12\pi
$$